# Port not freed as soon as program exist in c# .net core

Tags: c#, windows, rest, .net-core-3.1

I have a C# .net core 3.1 console application that acts as a REST web server. It runs as a Windows Service. It works well, but after I shutdown the application(or it goes down on some operation), I am unable to start the application immediately. I get the following error,

```
Unable to start Kestrel. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://[::]:8000: address already in use.

---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address(protocol/network/address/port) is normally permitted.

--->System.Net.Sockets.SocketException(10048): Only one usage of each socket address(protocol/network/address/port) is normally permitted.
.
.
.
```

If I try after maybe 5 minutes or so, I can start the application. Is there something I should do or I can do to free the binding on the port before I go down in the application?

#Update - 1
I use the following to shutdown the application under errors, etc,

```
_hostLifetime.StopApplication();
```

This is the code that initializes the webserver,

```
webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseUrls(restPort.Value);
```

The constructor of the Startup class is as follows,

```
_httpListener = new HttpListener();
```

The `Configure` method  in the Startup class has the following code,

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that manage the web server?

Comment: Can you specify `shutdown`?

Comment: *"Failed to vind to address"* - *"is notmally permitted"* - Are those actual error messages, typos and all?

Comment: "exist" - probably another typo. Guess it's "exits".

Comment: @vernou I have updated the question with some more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close a NetCore application it doesnt call code to terminate the running service. It just terminates, which means the code isn't called to close the connection. You need to make sure any code which opens a port is wrapped in a `using` so that it can dispose correctly. In a Windows Service, there should be a method for OnStop which you need to handle and explicitly close the connection.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstop?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

If the problem still happens, the only way I've found to resolve it is to reboot my machine